# Warping cursor from local coordinates when using several screens

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to warp the mouse using NSWindow local coordinates (but I'm starting from local coordinates in px instead of pt, with the y-axis reversed).

```
-(void)setProperRelativeMouseLocationTo:(NSPoint)loc
{
  CGFloat scale = [[m_window screen] backingScaleFactor];
  NSPoint point = NSMakePoint(loc.x / scale, loc.y / scale);

  point.y = [m_view frame].size.height - point.y;

  NSRect rect = NSZeroRect;
  rect.origin = point;
  rect = [m_window convertRectToScreen:rect];
  point = rect.origin;

  const float screenHeight = [[m_window screen] frame].size.height;
  point.y = screenHeight - point.y;

  warpCursor(point);
}

void warpCursor(NSPoint loc)
{
  CGPoint newCursorPosition = CGPointMake(loc.x, loc.y);
  CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(newCursorPosition);
}
```

However, the result is unexpected on one of my screens, the x-axis is correct, but the y-axis is off by `280pt`.
This value is not random, it corresponds to the gap between the two screens I'm using : the left is `1280*800` (pt) and the second one is `1920*1080` (pt) (the left one has backing scale factor of `2`, while the right one has factor `1`).

On the left screen, the mouse is warped exactly where it should be (if I read its local coordinates, they correspond to the ones I asked it to warp to).

Comment: `NSRect` doesn't have a field named `local`, so `rect.local = local` won't compile. It would be better for you to put your real, unmodified code in your question.

Comment: You're right, doing that.

Comment: Is there a reason to use an event tap instead of `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition`?

Comment: I guess there isn't. To be honest, this is strongly inspired by SFML source code. This doesn't change the problem though.

Comment: @robmayoff It seems that using even taps is less "binding" than `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition` as you suggested. The idea is to put the mouse back to the center of the view at every frame in order to move the camera with it. However, with `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition`, the mouse is 'stuck' in the middle, and we can't move the camera.

Comment: I'm not following where the discussion of event taps came from or is going, but have you considered using `CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(false)` to prevent the cursor from moving as the mouse moves? You would continue to get mouse-moved events. The location would not change, but they would carry valid `deltaX` and `deltaY` values.

Comment: Yes, if you want to track mouse movement without letting the cursor move, `CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition` is the way to go. I've used it and it's much simpler than warping the cursor.

Comment: Thanks, it's one of the things I would have liked to use, however, as I'm writing something that is supposedly cross-platform, every design choice I make as to take into account its feasibility in Xlib for instance, but I'll keep that in mind as a better design choice, thank you both so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa screen coordinates have their origin at the lower-left of the primary screen. Core Graphics coordinates have their origin at the top-left of the primary screen. Therefore, you have to use the primary screen's height to convert between the two.

You have:

```
  const float screenHeight = [[m_window screen] frame].size.height;
  point.y = screenHeight - point.y;
```

You need:

```
  const float screenHeight = [[NSScreen screens][0] frame].size.height;
  point.y = screenHeight - point.y;
```

Comment: I see, so there is a different between the global coordinates of the screens and the ones of Core Graphics. Thanks a lot!